# mysqli_query() Empty query

Tags: php

Tengo este código par extraer los id de los campos de una tabla y tengo dos errores en la consulta. Me sale como que en estas variables no hay información, se encuentran vacíos.

Exactamente los errores dicen dice:

Warning: mysqli_query():Empty query on line 16
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean given

```
**<?php

    include_once "conexion1.php";

    if(!empty($_POST)){


        if (empty($_POST['id'])) {
            # code...
        }else{

            $id = $_POST['id'];

            $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE id = $id");
            //en $resultado marca null   
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
            //en $rs tambieb, el mismo error que el renglon de arriba
            $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado,MYSQLI_NUM);

            $json[] = $rs;

            echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

    }

?>**
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es el id? No te faltaran comillas. En vez de ponerlo dentro del string de consulta, prueba con concatenarlo y ver cual es la consulta que vas a ejecutar. La conexión, la haces con mysqli... ¿no te olvidaras de la i?

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba previamente que el valor que pasas es numérico, puedes modificar para asegurarlo de esta forma:

```
intval($id)
```

O comprobar con un eco:

```
echo is_numeric($id)
```